# C Segmentation fault when adding hash node

Tags: c, hash

I have a structure of type:

```
struct hashnode_s {
    struct hashnode_s *next;
    char *key;
    ValueType tag;
    union
    {
        int IntegerValue;
        char *StringValue;
    } u;
    int IsInCycle;
};
```

And when I add an item of a type String, I have can, the code for it is

```
int hashtbl_InsertString(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key, const char *value)
{
    struct hashnode_s *node;
    hash_size hash;

    hash = SearchForHashIndex(hashtbl, key,value);

    if(hash == -1)
    {
        hash=hashtbl->hashfunc(key);
    }
    /* adding the first node  if not applicable (this is based on value string)*/

    if(hashtbl->nodes[hash]== NULL)
    {
        node = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s));
        node->key = key;
        node->tag = StringConst;
        node->u.StringValue = value;
        node->next = NULL;
        hashtbl->nodes[hash] = node;
    }
    else
    {
        node = hashtbl->nodes[hash];

        if(node->next ==NULL)
        {
            struct hashnode_s *nextNode;
            nextNode = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s));

            if(strcmp(node->u.StringValue,key)==0)
            {
                /* set next */
                nextNode->key = key;
                nextNode->tag = StringConst;
                nextNode->u.StringValue = value;
                nextNode->next = NULL;
                node->next = nextNode;
                hashtbl->nodes[hash] = node;
            }
            else if(strcmp(node->key, value)==0)
            {
                /* switch node positions if the key */
                nextNode->key = key;
                nextNode->tag = StringConst;
                nextNode->u.StringValue = value;
                node->next = NULL;
                nextNode->next = node;
                node = nextNode;
                hashtbl->nodes[hash] = nextNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            while(node)
            {
                struct hashnode_s *nextNode;
                nextNode = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s));

                /* TESTING PURPOSES ONLY
                printf("#define %s %s\n",node->key,node->u.StringValue);
                printf("%s==%s\n",node->u.StringValue,key);
                printf("%s==%s\n\n\n",node->key, value);
                */

                if(strcmp(node->u.StringValue,key)==0)
                {
                    nextNode->key = key;
                    nextNode->tag = StringConst;
                    nextNode->u.StringValue = value;
                    nextNode->next = NULL;
                    node->next = nextNode;
                    return 0;
                }
                else if(strcmp(node->key, value)==0)
                {
                    nextNode->key = key;
                    nextNode->tag = StringConst;
                    nextNode->u.StringValue = value;
                    node->next = NULL;
                    nextNode->next = node;
                    node = nextNode;
                    return 0;
                }
                node = node->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I add an item of the type integer. It throws a segmentation fault for some reason?

Here's that code.

```
int hashtbl_InsertValue(HASHTBL *hashtbl, const char *key, int integerValue)
{
    struct hashnode_s *node;
    hash_size hash;

    hash = SearchByKey(hashtbl, key);
    if(hash == -1)
    {
        hash=hashtbl->hashfunc(key);
    }

    if(hashtbl->nodes[hash] ==NULL)
    {
        node = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s));
        node->key = key;
        node->tag = IntegerConst;
        node->u.IntegerValue = integerValue;
        node->next = NULL;
        hashtbl->nodes[hash] = node;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        node = hashtbl->nodes[hash];
        //Check(hashtbl);
        while(node)
        {
            if(strcmp(node->u.StringValue,key)==0)
            {
                struct hashnode_s *nextNode;
                nextNode = malloc(sizeof(struct hashnode_s));

                nextNode->key = key;
                nextNode->tag = IntegerConst;

                nextNode->u.IntegerValue = 5;
                nextNode->next = NULL;

                if(node->next == NULL)
                {
                    // THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES AT!
                    node->next = nextNode;
                }

                return 0;
            }
            node=node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get rid of the segmentation fault, but I can't any ideas?

Comment: the area node->next = next node is what throws the segmentation fault. this is really annoying. i can't finish without getting past this!!

Comment: Use a debugger to see where the crash is. For example in gdb type backtrace after the program has failed.

Comment: `if(strcmp(node->u.StringValue,key)==0)` what if you stored an Integer in the node? u.StringValue should point to some bogus address. My guess is that you misunderstood what `union` does. In your case the integer and the pointer share the same data, not the integer and the key as you intended. Leave the union out (no need for this optimization).

Comment: You should really check the return code of `malloc` in case it returns 0 (no more memory). It would cause a segfault in your code, but is probably not the reason (seems unlikely you are out of memory).

Comment: I know exactly where it crashed, i just don't know why it throws the segmantation fault.

Comment: I second getting a stack trace/line no. of the failure. Attach gdb or gather a core file and examine it with gdb to find the failing stack/line.

Comment: @Kevin: please update the question with the exact location of the crash

Comment: You haven't shown the code for `SearchForHashIndex()` or `SearchbyKey()`, or how you are calling the functions (the compiling `main()` that calls the functions), so it is more difficult to assess where your problem is than it could be.  There seem to be a lot of quasi-random blank lines, too.  There also seems to be a lot of repeated code in there - are you sure you can't compress it with some more or less general data insertion functions?

Comment: I updated on where it crashed. I don't know why but If i create a node with a string type of union. it works. But once i create it with a int type of union it throws a segmentation fault.

Comment: SearchForHashIndex and SearchByKey works perfectly.

Comment: btw, i am trying to build a compiler, it's using Yylex so you don't really need the main lol

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it crashes at the point you marked in the code?  Unless you have a buffer overflow somewhere (which I'll give you the benefit of the doubt) which corrupts the `node` variable or the pointer was initialized to garbage (due to an invalid index in `hashtbl->nodes[hash]`), there should no problem.  I'd check your hash table implementation again and verify that the node does indeed exist before proceeding.  p.s., it will help improve readability of your code immensely if you move the code which initializes a node in a separate function.

Comment: It seems that when i state " nextNode->key = key;
                nextNode->tag = IntegerConst;

                nextNode->u.IntegerValue = 5;
                nextNode->next = NULL;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// change to   nextNode->key = key;
                nextNode->tag = StringConst;

                nextNode->u.StringValue = 5;
                nextNode->next = NULL;
it doesn't have a problem.... but once i have it as an integer. it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few immediate issues spring to my attention when looking at your code:

1. You always do a strcmp with StringValue even though it is in a union with IntegerValue, this means that strcmp will read an invalid memory address and cause a segfault for integer values.
2. Is your hash-table initialized, if not then it's quite likely that the line of code you claim is segfaulting because it is the first time a write occurs on a page without write access.
3. You check if the next node is NULL before assigning the allocated node to be the next node, if it fails then you don't free the memory, this memory leaking could be an issue. The obvious solution to number 1 and this would be to use the next pointer being NULL as an indicator that you've reached the end of the list rather than checking the string which may not always be there.
4. The hash is a signed integer, ensure that the only negative number returned from the hashing function is -1 since any other negative could easily be another out-of-bounds access error.

If I were you then I'd fix these other problems before trying to track down this error, it's easier to find an error when you're only looking for one.